# Why aren't you automatically warned when a comment of your is deleted as offensive?

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, offensive

Recently I caustically commented a just-do-it-for-me question by an old user with "More than 7000 (!) reputation points without trying to do something by yourself and adding an MWE?"

My comment was deleted as offensive, but I realized it only by chance.

Since I used the same comment many times in the past for similar situations, I would have continued to use it in the future if I hadn't known it was considered offensive.

Why is there no sort of warning when a comment of yours is deleted for that reason?